How to add a third level in TikZ tree
I've been really struggling to get my code in Overleaf to construct a third level of my gametree. The closest I've gotten is the below code, but even then I'm finding it hard to read and understand what each bracket and {} does, which has made troubleshooting much harder.
I've looked through the documentation but it feels like it's in a different syntax than what I've been putting in. Even weird stuff, like the center command only working with certain sibling distances (probably unrelated to my current problem though, and something I can workaround). Does anybody have any pointers? I'd greatly appreciate it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\title{TikZ Sandbox}
\date{September 2024}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{hollow node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.5]
\tikzstyle{solid node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=60mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=30mm]


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent/.style={draw}]


\node[solid node,label=above:{$s_1$}]{}[level distance = 40mm]
    child{node(0-1)[solid node,label=left:{$s_2$}]{}
        child{node(0-1-1)[solid node,label=left:{$s_a$}]{}
        edge from parent  node[left] {\small$b_a$}}
            child{node[solid node,label=left:{$s_b$}]{}}
        child{node(0-1-2)[solid node,label=left:{$s_c$}]{}
        edge from parent  node[right] {\small$b_b$}}
        edge from parent  node[left,xshift=-6] {\small$b_c$}}%s1 to s2
    child{node(0-2)[solid node,label=left:{$s_2$}]{}
        child{node(0-2-1)[solid node,label=right:{$s_3$}]{}
        edge from parent  node[left] {\small$b_1$}}
        child{node(0-2-2)[solid node,label=left:{$s_3$}]{}
        edge from parent  node[right] {\small$b_3$}}
        edge from parent  node[left] {\small$b_2$}}
    child{node(0-3)[solid node,label=left:{$s_2$}]{}
        child{node(0-3-1)[solid node,label=right:{$s_3$}]{}
        edge from parent  node[left] {\small$b_1$}}
        child{node(0-3-2)[solid node,label=right:{$s_3$}]{}
        edge from parent  node[] {\small$b_2$}}
        edge from parent  node[right,xshift=6] {\small$b_3$}}
;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

off-topic: don't use \tikzstyle. it's obsolete. use \tikzset{} instead. I'd recommend looking at an alternative - either forest or, since it is a game tree, istgame. these are more powerful and, at least in the case of forest, the code is much easier to parse.

your code produces 3 levels already, if you include the root node. do you want another level or do you want to change something about the current levels?

My bad, I wasn't counting the root node. I was looking to add a fourth level.  I just looked into forest and it definitely seems easier to look through, I should be able to use this and actually be able to read my code. Thanks!

Here's a version with forest. It needs tidying up a bit, but that's mostly tweaking positioning of labels etc. If your actual tree has this many leaves, you will probably need to turn it. The rotating package provides sidewaysfigure for this purpose.
mel is a style for setting the edge label more-or-less automatically. It takes a single argument which should be the content of the label. Don't include $...$ as it will be automatically wrapped in those, as will the main labels for the nodes.
If you need to draw several trees, forest can slow things down considerably. In this case, consider externalising the images. memoize is probably the best option in this case, as it is by the same author and so works out-of-the-box. However, memoize is not yet available on Overleaf.

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  solid node/.style = {circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
}
\begin{forest}
  maths label/.style={label=left:{$#1$}},
  mel/.style={%
    edge label/.process={ On= ? {n'}{1}  {node [midway,right] {$#1$}}{node [midway,left] {$#1$}}},
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    for tree={%
      maths label/.option=content,
      delay={content={}},
      solid node,
      if={ > On=  {n children}{3} }{calign=child edge,calign primary child=2}{},
    },
  },
  for tree={%
    s sep'+=5mm,
    l sep'+=10mm,
  },
  [s_1
    [s_2, mel=b_c
      [s_a, mel=b_a
        [s_4,mel=c_1]
        [s_4,mel=c_2]
        [s_4,mel=c_3]
      ]
      [s_b
        [s_4,mel=c_1]
        [s_4,mel=c_2]
      ]
      [s_c, mel=b_c
        [s_4,mel=c_1]
        [s_4,mel=c_2]
        [s_4,mel=c_3]
      ]
    ]
    [s_2, mel=b_2
      [s_3, mel=b_1
        [s_4,mel=c_1]
        [s_4,mel=c_2]
      ]
      [s_3, mel=b_3
        [s_4,mel=c_1]
        [s_4,mel=c_2]
        [s_4,mel=c_3]
      ]
    ]
    [s_2, mel=b_3
      [s_3, mel=b_1
        [s_4,mel=c_1]
        [s_4,mel=c_2]
        [s_4,mel=c_3]
      ]
      [s_3, mel=b_2
        [s_4,mel=c_1]
        [s_4,mel=c_2]
        [s_4,mel=c_3]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


This looks great! I should have posted an update, but I used forest to get something very similar looking. I tried to paste the code but it went over the character limit, so just imagine a tree that looks like yours but with slightly different labels and sloppier code.
It definitely would have been easier to use mel though. I'll have to look into rotating it since I've been having some trouble fitting it into my document. Thanks!
